Locally render a tile exactly like mod_tile/renderd would
I'm slowly learning the machinery involved in running a custom tile server for openstreetmap. I have a fully functioning setup more or less straight from this switch2osm guide but I'm curious about one small detail.
What exactly happens when a specific tile image is requested, and it has to be rendered?
For example, navigating to an area in my slippy map example fills the window with a set of images, one will be http://localhost/hot/18/167359/98893.png
I understand that accessing that URI will invoke mod_tile which in turns tells renderd to render the missing tile using the information in /etc/renderd.conf. This tile is essentially a PNG (stored with neighboring tiles) and served as such back to the client.
My goal is to be able to render it from the command line or in a small script exactly as it would be rendered with mod_tile/renderd - including round-off details and bounding conditions between tiles.
Is there a command line client that can generate the PNG files exactly as would be done given only the information given to mod_tile but without going through mod_tile?
